# Issues with links not working only in Chrome on new Ghost blog

Tags: html, google-chrome, azure, ghost-blog

I've recently been experimenting with Ghost and am in the process of converting my personal website from Wordpress to Ghost.  But it appears as though there is some issues with the pages rendering.  If I change the `DocType` to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

From this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

The page will at least render with working links in Chrome, but does introduce some other formatting issues.

I've worked with the W3C validator and cannot find anything that is obviously missing from my new site vs. an example site that works just fine.  The page also seems to work just fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer.  I'm attempting to run this new site that isn't working on Azure.

#### WORKING

http://ghosted.me/the-best-theme-for-bloggers/

#### NOT WORKING

http://rsolberg.azurewebsites.net/welcome-to-ghost/

Answer (score 0):

had to review the themes CSS in great detail and pay close attention to the Z-Index.  It appears the `footer.foot` CSS class had set the `z-index:-2` and I was able to fix this by setting it to `z-index:0`

### phantom/assets/css/style.css

```
footer.foot {
    width: 100%;
    background: #0F2036;
    padding: 95px 0 75px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
```